# Dynamically assign 'active' class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to dynamically assign different links the class`"active"` in order to change the CSS. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

```
<div class="livello2">
    <div class="live">
        <a href="./Live.php"><img src="templates/css/comp/pulsante_live_off.png"></a>
    </div>
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul>
            <a href="./index.php"><li>HOME</li></a>
            <a href="./Concerti.php"><li>CONCERTI</li></a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

---

I have this:

```
<div class="livello2">
                 <div class="live">
                     <a href="./Live.php"><img src="templates/css/comp/pulsante_live_off.png"></a>
                 </div>
                 <nav class="menu">
                     <ul>
                         <a href="./index.php"><li>HOME</li></a>
                         <a href="./Concerti.php"><li>CONCERTI</li></a>

                     </ul>
                 </nav>
       </div>
```

I think the jquery script should be something like:

```
click(function(){
   $link.removeClass('active');
    $link2.addClass('active');
  });
```

Comment: could you please rephrase this question or provide some example code? it's kinda hard to understand what you need here

Comment: Did you menu, you need to show active status in link?

Comment: @Dhamu Congrats man, you managed to make less sense than the OP

Comment: Any of the answers should help here, but out of curiosity, since you are going back to the server to reload the page, your javascript changes will not stick... I think you will have to generate the page in php with the `active` class assigned to the proper link based on the page you are on...

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("yourElementsId").classList.toggle("active");
```

This first gets the item you wish to modify by its id and then simply toggles the "active" class. You can also use the following methods:

```
classList.add("active");
classList.remove("active");
```

---

To do this in jQuery you simply do the following:

```
$("#yourElementsId").addClass("active");
$("#yourElementsId").removeClass("active");
$("#yourElementsId").toggleClass("active");
```

Comment: The question is tagged jQuery, not tagged JavaScript :)

Comment: @nbrooks You almost sound like you're saying that they're different things -- hint: they're not.

Comment: @abody97 They are certainly different tags, and a quick glance at the question will show that it is not tagged JavaScript. Also, if you're suggesting that JavaScript and jQuery are generally synonymous, you're also wrong. jQuery is a library written in JavaScript. That does not make it the same as JavaScript. Anyway, this is immaterial—I was simply correcting levib's comment that the question didn't mention a specific library.

Comment: @nbrooks jQuery and JavaScript aren't synonymous, but if someone is using jQuery, then surely that someone can use a pure JavaScript solution (such as the first one mentioned in the answer). Anyway, yeah; this isn't constructive :)

Comment: @abody97 Oh I wasn't disagreeing with that, sure, a 'pure' JS solution is always acceptable. Like I said, before there was a comment saying he wouldn't add any library-specific code because the question didn't mention a library, so I was just correcting that. Thanks for clarifying though :)

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes that you want add "active" to the menu links:

HTML:

```
<div class="livello2">
    <div class="live">
        <a href="./Live.php"><img src="templates/css/comp/pulsante_live_off.png"></a>
    </div>
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="./index.php">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="./Concerti.php">CONCERTI</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.menu a').click(function(e) {
        // you usually want to prevent default for handling link clicks,
        // otherwise the browser follows the href (if that's intended skip this)
        e.preventDefault();

        $('.menu a').not(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```